# Disable windows "debugging window" when calling program from the command line

Tags: c#, .net

I am starting a command line app from a C# application, this command line app is another C# application and from time to time it raises an exception and dies, this is not an issue in general and the code knows how to handle this case.

The issue is that whenever it raises this error that windows debugging window is shown. Is there any way I can disable that from the calling program? Like a `ProcessStartInfo` property I can use to prevent it from happening?

I can also change the command line program as well, but I´d rather not do it.

Comment: You are only getting the debugging window as you have visual studio / some other SDK installed - there is no built in Windows debug window. A normal user will not get it but may get a different effect if your code is not handling it properly. You need to try it on a computer without VS or any other SDKs installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are seeing is the [Just-In-Time Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx), to make your program excluded from the list of detected programs that will launch the debugger you must put the name of your exe in the following registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\AutoExclusionList
```

If you are running a 64 bit version of windows you should also add the exe name to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\AutoExclusionList
```

Create a new REG_DWORD value, name it `YourAppName.exe` and set the value to `1`.

See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634(v=vs.85).aspx#Excluding_an_Application_from_Automatic_Debugging) for more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The error is obviously caused by an unhandled exception.

Assuming it is a command line application, why don't you just put a `try ... catch` block wrapping the entire `Main` method and handle the exception in the appropriate way, like returning an error code to the console or something else you need/want to do.